# TLS 1.2 server client code using schannel - certfificate issue

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, tls1.3, mtls, starttls

I have two systems. One of them is running the client and the other one is running the server. Both are having client and server certificates by their domain name, but the handshake is failing.

When these programs are running on the same system with a common certificate, they are showing output and the handshake is happening.

I created new certificates with the same domain and used them in both the client and the server.